# In SNMP, Can we remove .0 from the end of a Scalar OID?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I have a situation, I have defined a scalar OID in my MIB but when I try to get value of the OID from the Agent using SNMP Get, it says "No OID exists" but when I append .0 at the end of the OID it replies with the value. I need to know can I make sure that this .0 at the end of the OID should not be required?

Answer (score 3):

The OID convention (`.0` for scalar objects) is part of SNMP standards, so cannot be altered for you alone.

Comment: I do not get this zero when I translate the MIB using snmptranslate tool. I am not sure whether its standard or open. Can you point me to the literature where I can read about this standard?

Comment: @Usman in case you want to read it https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3781#section-2.2 `snmptranslate` is strictly a tool to translate OIDs, so it won't be able to help you learn whether an OID is scalar or not. You need to utilize the MIB related APIs to parse the documents and extract that information on your own.